# Openshift setting env or patching env

Tags: openshift

Can some one help me how to set env when then the value has more than one values
Ex:

```
{name: Java_opts
 value: '-D spring.profiles.active =dev'
 name : test
 valuev: test}
```

I want to replace  java opts like below without replacing other variables

```
{
 name :Java_opts
 Value :'-D spring.profiles.active =dev Djava.ssl.truststore=dev/test
{
```

I have tries follwing ways

```
Oc set env dc/service "Java_opts  ="-D spring.profiles.active =dev -Djava.ssl.truststore=dev/tesr
```

It is give an error as we are passing two values  for java_opts

**Second approch:**

I have tried oc patch command

This command is replacing the complete env section

Can somebody help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

Setting an environment variable to multiple values is not possible, however in your case you just want to add multiple arguments, which is of course possible. Also, `oc set env` allows you to set multiple variables at once.

So to set multiple JAVA_OPTS and also TEST, use the following command:

```
oc set env dc/my-deploymentconf JAVA_OPTS="-Dspring.profiles.active=dev -Djava.ssl.truststore=dev/test" TEST="abc"
```

Comment: Thanka for quick response   we havrissed thr qoutesb, thats why i am getting error